# Opencart: removing "billing address" checkout step

Tags: php, opencart

Using Opencart v3:

I have a store that sells digital goods, so we dont need the billing address from our customers. The 2nd checkout step is the "billing address" step. I would like to remove this.

Also, the third step is the payment method. We only use paypal so its always the default payment. How do I remove the payment method step, whilst keeping paypal the default, on-selected option?

I know there are extension for this, but I'd just like to know if there is a quick and easy fix for this, thank you

Comment: if your problem solved, mart that answer as Solved

Comment: the problem has not been solved, please view my comment to that answer

Answer (score 0):

As you are selling digital goods, you dont need to specify the billing address, delivery method. Opencart has built in features. From the Admin panel Go to your product catalog and set all product settings to `Shipping Required: NO`

if you want to set paypal as your default, you have to remove the other payment option. From the Admin panel Go to Payments then you will be able to see the enabled payment option, `click edit the Cash On Delivery method and set disable or any other payment option set to disable` . There will be only paypal as your payment option then it will be auto selected option on the checkout for payment. For more info Visit [here](http://docs.opencart.com/extension/payment/)

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to remove: https://ibb.co/fY9Xsb


as you can see, there is the billing address step, and payment method step. I would like to bypass the billing address step, and the payment method step. The payment method should be defaulted to paypal express. Is there anyway to do this?

In regards to the payment method, yes it is defaulted to paypal express because it is the only option. However, the step is still there. How can I just remove the payment method step?